Having problems installing the Zebra search engine (https://www.indexdata.com/resources/software/zebra/) in a docker container
The Dockerfile:

    # Use an official Debian runtime as a parent image
    FROM debian:latest

    # Set environment variables
    ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

    # Install necessary packages
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y wget build-essential autoconf automake pkg-config libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev tcl-dev libbz2-dev libtool xsltproc inkscape

    # Install YAZ
    RUN apt-get install -y libyaz-dev

    # Verify YAZ installation
    RUN pkg-config --cflags yaz && pkg-config --libs yaz

    # Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to ensure configure script can find YAZ
    ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig

    # Download and install Zebra
    RUN wget http://ftp.indexdata.dk/pub/zebra/idzebra-2.2.7.tar.gz
    RUN tar -xzf idzebra-2.2.7.tar.gz
    RUN cd idzebra-2.2.7 && \
        ./configure && \
        make && \
        make install

    # Create a directory for Zebra configuration and data
    RUN mkdir -p /etc/zebra /var/lib/zebra

    # Copy default configuration files (you can customize these as needed)
    COPY zebra.cfg /etc/zebra/zebra.cfg
    COPY zebra-bib1.att /etc/zebra/zebra-bib1.att

    # Expose the port Zebra will run on
    EXPOSE 210

    # Start Zebra
    CMD ["zebraidx", "-c", "/etc/zebra/zebra.cfg", "update", "record"]
    CMD ["zebrasrv", "-f", "/etc/zebra/zebra.cfg"]

The container creation breaks with the error

configure: error: YAZ development libraries required

Note that the installation of the YAZ libraries has been verified (RUN pkg-config --cflags yaz && pkg-config --libs yaz).
The same error happens with Ubuntu as the parent image.
